# How to find both rows associated with a string in an R dataframe and subtract their mutual column values

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    sample  value  gene  tag       isPTV
1   1120    3.4    arx1  1120|arx1  0
2   2123    2.3    mnf2  2123|mnf2  0
3   1129    1.9    trf4  1129|trf4  0
4   2198    0.2    brc1  2198|brc1  0
5   1120    2.1    arx1  1120|arx1  1
6   2123    0.4    mnf2  2123|mnf2  1
7   1129    1.2    trf4  1129|trf4  1
8   2198    0.9    brc1  2198|brc1  1
```

Such that `0` means `false` and `1` means `true`. What I'm ultimately trying to do is create a dataframe that, for each `tag`, finds the absolute value between the `value` numbers.

For instance, for `1129|trf4` occurs in two separate rows. There's a value for when it `isPTV` and when it is not, so the absolute value would be `1.9` - `1.2` = `0.7`.

I started out by trying to write a function to do these for a given `tag` value, such that, for a given tag, it would return both rows containing the tag:

```
getExprValue <- function(dataframe, tag){
  return(dataframe[tag,])
}
```

But this is not working, and I'm not very familiar with how you index dataframes in R.

What is the right way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

**Solution 1 Attempt:**

`m_diff <- m %>% group_by(tag) %>% mutate(absDiff = abs(diff(value)))`

Response:

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column`absDiff`must be length 1 (the group size), not 0`

**Solution 2 Attempt:**

`with(df1, abs(ave(value, tag, FUN = diff)))`

Response:

`Error in x[i] <- value[[j]] : replacement has length zero`

Comment: Do you need `with(df1, abs(tapply(value, tag, FUN = diff)))` or if you need as a column `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(tag) %>% mutate(absDiff = abs(diff(value)))`

Comment: I would use akrun' s second option with dplyr~

Comment: @akrun's code with `ave` would also give a column: `with(df1, abs(ave(value, tag, FUN = diff)))`.

Comment: See **UPDATE** above with both solutions attempted.

Comment: It results in error, if the number of elements are more than 2 per group.  You need `c(NA, diff(value))`

Comment: I tried `m_diff <- m %>% group_by(tag) %>% mutate(absDiff = abs(c(NA, diff(value))))`, but the absDiff column is entirely `NA`

Comment: The solution is based on the example you provided and both the solution I posted earlier works for that.  If you have a data that is not in the same form, it needs to be updated.  You can also check the `class` of 'value'  Is it `numeric` or not?

Comment: Yes, I checked and it's `numeric`

Comment: Also, check if there are 'tag' having only 0' or 1 ie. only one row i.e. `all(table(m$tag)==2)`

Comment: Ah okay, it said `FALSE`

Comment: That means you need a condition to make it successful.  Assuming that there are not more than 2, `m %>% group_by(tag) %>% mutate(absDiff = if(n() == 1) value else abs(diff(value)))`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I just noticed that @akrun had a much simpler solution**

Create data with a structure similar to yours:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  sample = rep(sample(1000:3000, 10), 2),
  value = rnorm(20, 5, 1),
  gene = rep(letters[1:10], 2),
  tag = paste(sample, gene, sep = "|"),
  isPTV = rep(0:1, each = 10)
)

dat

#> # A tibble: 20 x 5
#>    sample value gene  tag    isPTV
#>     <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <int>
#>  1   2149  5.90 a     2149|a     0
#>  2   1027  5.46 b     1027|b     0
#>  3   1103  5.65 c     1103|c     0
#>  4   1884  4.86 d     1884|d     0
#>  5   2773  5.58 e     2773|e     0
#>  6   2948  6.98 f     2948|f     0
#>  7   2478  5.17 g     2478|g     0
#>  8   2724  6.71 h     2724|h     0
#>  9   1927  5.06 i     1927|i     0
#> 10   1081  4.39 j     1081|j     0
#> 11   2149  4.60 a     2149|a     1
#> 12   1027  2.97 b     1027|b     1
#> 13   1103  6.17 c     1103|c     1
#> 14   1884  5.83 d     1884|d     1
#> 15   2773  4.23 e     2773|e     1
#> 16   2948  6.48 f     2948|f     1
#> 17   2478  5.06 g     2478|g     1
#> 18   2724  5.32 h     2724|h     1
#> 19   1927  7.32 i     1927|i     1
#> 20   1081  4.73 j     1081|j     1
```

@akrun solution (much better than mine):

```
dat %>%
  group_by(tag) %>%
  mutate(absDiff = abs(diff(value)))

#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#> # Groups:   tag [10]
#>    sample value gene  tag    isPTV absDiff
#>     <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <int>   <dbl>
#>  1   2149  5.90 a     2149|a     0   1.30 
#>  2   1027  5.46 b     1027|b     0   2.49 
#>  3   1103  5.65 c     1103|c     0   0.520
#>  4   1884  4.86 d     1884|d     0   0.974
#>  5   2773  5.58 e     2773|e     0   1.34 
#>  6   2948  6.98 f     2948|f     0   0.502
#>  7   2478  5.17 g     2478|g     0   0.114
#>  8   2724  6.71 h     2724|h     0   1.39 
#>  9   1927  5.06 i     1927|i     0   2.26 
#> 10   1081  4.39 j     1081|j     0   0.337
#> 11   2149  4.60 a     2149|a     1   1.30 
#> 12   1027  2.97 b     1027|b     1   2.49 
#> 13   1103  6.17 c     1103|c     1   0.520
#> 14   1884  5.83 d     1884|d     1   0.974
#> 15   2773  4.23 e     2773|e     1   1.34 
#> 16   2948  6.48 f     2948|f     1   0.502
#> 17   2478  5.06 g     2478|g     1   0.114
#> 18   2724  5.32 h     2724|h     1   1.39 
#> 19   1927  7.32 i     1927|i     1   2.26 
#> 20   1081  4.73 j     1081|j     1   0.337
```

My initial suggestion (unnecessarily complicated):

```
nested <- dat %>%
  group_by(tag) %>%
  nest()

nested %>%
  mutate(difference = map(data, ~ abs(diff(.$value)))) %>%
  select(- data) %>% 
  unnest()

#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    tag    difference
#>    <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 2149|a      1.30 
#>  2 1027|b      2.49 
#>  3 1103|c      0.520
#>  4 1884|d      0.974
#>  5 2773|e      1.34 
#>  6 2948|f      0.502
#>  7 2478|g      0.114
#>  8 2724|h      1.39 
#>  9 1927|i      2.26 
#> 10 1081|j      0.337
```